# F#: Adding an interface (like IComparable) to an existing type (e.g. from a library like Fare)

Tags: inheritance, interface, f#, functional-programming, fare

*Context*: I'm using the .net/c#-library [Fare](https://github.com/moodmosaic/Fare) in F# and I try to use e.g. `Map.ofSeq`. This fails as `Fare.State` does not support comparision since it does not implement the `System.IComprable` interface (FS0001).

In my naivity, I tried to add the `interface IComparable` like this:

```fs
type Fare.State with
    interface IComparable<Fare.State> with
        member this.CompareTo obj =
                               match box obj with
                               | :? Fare.State as other -> this.Id.CompareTo other.Id
                               | _ -> invalidArg "obj" "not a State"
```

This however is impossible as F# requires the implemented interfaces should be declared on the initial declaration of the type (FS0909).

I thought of the following works-arounds:

1. Introducing a wrapper-type that includes a `Fare.State`  as its only attribute and implements `IComparable`
2. Storing the ID instead of the actual `Fare.State` and use a Map to translate to the actual state where needed
3. Use some trick to add `interface IComparable` to the existing type.

If the third option is impossible, which option is most appropriate? Are there other options?

Comment: May a *4th* option be to open a Pull Request in [Fare](https://github.com/moodmosaic/Fare) proposing to implement that interface?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure whether the c#-developers are very interested in adding code to make the life of the f#-friends easier.

Comment: Fare's `State` *does* implement `IComperable` though [(source)](https://github.com/moodmosaic/Fare/blob/f453ef1ef07f1f9e52851239a8aa477ef86ea1f1/Src/Fare/State.cs#L44).

Comment: I'll defer to @NikosBaxevanis on Fare's capabilities since he's the author, so instead I'll ask for a complete example where you are running into the error where the compiler is saying that `State` does not implement `IComparable<State>`.

Comment: F# comparison constraint looks for (non-generic) `IComparable`, which (generic) `IComparable<'T>` doesn't inherit from.

Comment: Implementing both generic and non-generic interface is also good C#. There must be a design guideline that says so somewhere.

Comment: Could you try updating to Fare 1.0.3 or newer? `State` now implements `IComperable` as well.

Comment: @NikosBaxevanis Thank you. The update actually solves my problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While `State` type does implement (generic) `IComparable<'T>`, what F# looks for in comparison constraint is (non-generic) `IComparable`. The fact that the former is not a subtype of the latter seems like a lamentable design choice, but it's here to stay.

Your workarounds 1 and 2 make sense to me. From a design point of view, I would prefer a simple record wrapper around `State`. But if ids are unique, going with your other workaround is conceivable, if a bit clunky.

Comment: `Id` is unique. In fact, the comparison is done relying on `Id` ([source](https://github.com/moodmosaic/Fare/blob/master/Src/Fare/State.cs#L223))